# Using information from object selected in jList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am having difficulty getting information from a jList so that it can be used to create an object in a different class when a button is clicked,

```
private void jButtonAddOrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    int noCopies;
    String title, Name;

    noCopies = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldCopies.getText());
    title = Book.bookInstances.get(jListPubBooks.getSelectedIndex()).getName();
    Name = Book.bookInstances.get(jListPubBooks.getSelectedIndex()).getPublisherName();
    new Order(noCopies, title, Name);
    setjlistmodel(Order.orderItem);
```

I am sure there are no problems with my setjlistmodel method as this works elsewhere in my program when only getting information from text fields. I think my problem is with these two lines:

```
        title = Book.bookInstances.get(jListPubBooks.getSelectedIndex()).getName();
    Name = Book.bookInstances.get(jListPubBooks.getSelectedIndex()).getPublisherName();

}
```

This is my order class;

```
package bookstore;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Order {
int noOfBooks;
String bookTitle;
String pubName;
public static ArrayList<Order> orderItem = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Order>> Order = new ArrayList<>();


public Order(int noBooks, String Title, String Name)
{
    this.noOfBooks = noBooks;
    this.bookTitle = Title;
    this.pubName = Name;
    orderItem.add(this);
}
public void addOrder(ArrayList ord)
{
    Order.add(ord);
}
public int getNoBooks()
{
    return noOfBooks;
}
public String getBookTitle()
{
    return bookTitle;
}
public String getPubName()
{
    return pubName;
}
}
```

setjlistmodel method:

```
private void setjlistmodel(ArrayList<Order> orderInstances){
    DefaultListModel OrderList = new DefaultListModel();
    for(int i = 0; i<=OrderList.size()-1;i++){
        OrderList.addElement(orderInstances.get(i).getNoBooks());

        System.out.println(orderInstances.get(i).getBookTitle());
        System.out.println(OrderList.firstElement());
    }

    jListOrder.setModel(OrderList);
}
```

The problem is that it is not displaying anything in jListOrder when the button is clicked. I don't think the Order is being added to the orderItem ArrayList.

Comment: What are the values of Name and title when you click the button? I'm also not sure why you don't just use ipthe instance of Book which is selected when creating the Order class, but hats just me...

Comment: Do you have any exception? What is your problem? Seems you forget ask a question. Post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Also post code for `setjlistmodel` method.

Comment: Sorry new to all of this...edited now to show setjlistmodel method and problem at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The problem is that it is not displaying anything in jListOrder when the button is clicked. I don't think the Order is being added to the orderItem ArrayList."*

I think adding an `orderItem` is fine.

`OrderList` size is zero when you first initialize it, which means your loops does absolutely nothing

```
DefaultListModel OrderList = new DefaultListModel();
for(int i = 0; i <= OrderList.size() - 1; i++)
```

You probably want

```
for(int i = 0; i <= orderInstances.size() - 1; i++)
```

Which is using the `ArrayList` size.

---

As a side note, please separate operators with space. It makes it easier to read.